# How do I use Serde to deserialize structs with references from a reader?

Tags: rust, yaml, deserialization, lifetime, serde

I have these structs:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct GGConf<'a> {
    #[serde(alias = "ssh")]
    #[serde(rename = "ssh")]
    #[serde(default)]
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub ssh_config: Option<SSHConfig<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct SSHConfig<'a> {
    #[serde(alias = "privateKey")]
    #[serde(rename = "privateKey")]
    private_key: &'a str,

    username: &'a str,
}
```

Deserialization happens when I read from a YAML file:

```
let mut config: GGConf = serde_yaml::from_reader(file)?;
```

On compiling, I get an error:

```
error: implementation of `conf::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_GGConf::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
   --> src/conf.rs:50:34
    |
50  |           let mut config: GGConf = serde_yaml::from_reader(file)?;
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `conf::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_GGConf::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
    |
   ::: /home/ninan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.98/src/de/mod.rs:524:1
    |
524 | / pub trait Deserialize<'de>: Sized {
525 | |     /// Deserialize this value from the given Serde deserializer.
526 | |     ///
527 | |     /// See the [Implementing `Deserialize`][impl-deserialize] section of the
...   |
562 | |     }
563 | | }
    | |_- trait `conf::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_GGConf::_serde::Deserialize` defined here
    |
    = note: `conf::GGConf<'_>` must implement `conf::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_GGConf::_serde::Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
    = note: ...but `conf::GGConf<'_>` actually implements `conf::_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_GGConf::_serde::Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I vaguely understand that serde deserialization also has a lifetime `'de` and that the compiler is confusing my lifetime specified for it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

How do I currently correctly deserialize the YAML into both structs?
Is there something I am missing here or misunderstood?

I looked at [How do I resolve "implementation of serde::Deserialize is not general enough" with actix-web's Json type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57976096/155423), but I cannot use an owned type. I need it to be a borrowed type.

I will try and write a playground example for this.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is impossible; you **must** use owned data instead of references.

Here's a minimal example:

```
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.104

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct SshConfig<'a> {
    username: &'a str,
}

fn example(file: impl std::io::Read) {
    serde_yaml::from_reader::<_, SshConfig>(file);
}
```

```
error: implementation of `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SshConfig::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
   --> src/lib.rs:9:5
    |
9   |       serde_yaml::from_reader::<_, SshConfig>(file);
    |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SshConfig::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
    | 
   ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.104/src/de/mod.rs:531:1
    |
531 | / pub trait Deserialize<'de>: Sized {
532 | |     /// Deserialize this value from the given Serde deserializer.
533 | |     ///
534 | |     /// See the [Implementing `Deserialize`][impl-deserialize] section of the
...   |
569 | |     }
570 | | }
    | |_- trait `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SshConfig::_serde::Deserialize` defined here
    |
    = note: `SshConfig<'_>` must implement `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SshConfig::_serde::Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
    = note: ...but `SshConfig<'_>` actually implements `_IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_SshConfig::_serde::Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

If you look at the definition of `serde_yaml::from_reader`, you'll see that it's limited to only deserializing owned data:

```
pub fn from_reader<R, T>(rdr: R) -> Result<T>
where
    R: Read,
    T: DeserializeOwned,
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The same is true for [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.48/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html) and probably any equivalent function.

You can only deserialize a type containing references *when there's data to reference*. Something implementing the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait only guarantees that it can copy some bytes into a user-provided buffer. Since the `from_reader` function doesn't accept that buffer as an argument, any buffer would be destroyed at the exit of `from_reader`, invalidating the references.

See also:

- [How do I resolve "implementation of serde::Deserialize is not general enough" with actix-web's Json type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57976096/155423)

---

If you **must** use references (and in many cases this isn't true), you will need to:

1. read from the reader yourself into a buffer
2. use `from_str` instead of `from_reader`
3. keep the buffer around as long as the deserialized data

Comment: Will try out the suggestion. I need the `SSHConfig` values  to be references as I will be overwriting  a static constant with the value from the file. Thus forcing me to have references.

Comment: @leoOrion Sounds like you want [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423). You won't be able to directly use references loaded from a file in your case as they won't be `'static` anyway.

Comment: Yes. I have a global mutable singleton with a default SSHConfig value which may or may not be overridden from the file.

Comment: [Global mutable singletons can have `String`s](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0773bb1b3e990c770cce302709420c36). I suspect you are suffering from [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281829).

Comment: Can this be achieved without `lazy_static`? I just removed all references and I get this error on creation of the singleton -> `error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants`. I am ok with using `lazy_static`. Just asking to know what is different.

Comment: @leoOrion yes it can be done without lazy_static, but no, it cannot be done without something *like* lazy_static. The singleton link from earlier shows alternatives. Chances are, your attempt at using a `static` would introduce undefined behavior.

Comment: One point I expanded on in my answer - `serde_yaml` doesn't support zero-copy deserialization currently (as of v0.8), so the `from_str` method still requires owned data types

Answer (score 6):

`from_reader` takes a stream of data from somewhere (anywhere which implements the Read trait) - it doesn't store the data, meaning nothing owns the data, therefore you cannot have a reference to that data in your struct. In other words, `from_reader` takes a transient stream of data, therefore needs a place to store the data.

An additional complication is that `serde_yaml` (at least for version 0.8.11) doesn't not support zero-copy deserialization:

> https://docs.rs/serde_yaml/0.8.11/serde_yaml/fn.from_str.html
>
> ```
> pub fn from_str<T>(s: &str) -> Result<T> where
>     T: DeserializeOwned,
> ```
>
> ...
>
> YAML currently does not support zero-copy deserialization.

Compare this to, say, `serde_json`, which does:

> https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.50/serde_json/de/fn.from_str.html
>
> ```
> pub fn from_str<'a, T>(s: &'a str) -> Result<T> where
>     T: Deserialize<'a>,
> ```

So, at least with something like `serde_json` you could use `from_str` from an owned buffer, and that will allow you to use references in your struct (but this will not work for `serde_yaml` currently)

```rust
// Written with rustc 1.42.0 and
// [dependencies]
// serde = "1.0.105"
// serde_derive = "1.0.105"
// serde_json = "1.0.50"

use std::io::Read;
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct SshConfig<'a> {
    username: &'a str,
}

fn main() {
    // Open file handle
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open("example.json").unwrap();

    // Read the data into a String, which stores (and thus owns) the data
    let mut strbuf = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut strbuf).unwrap();

    // Deserialize into struct, which references
    let result: SshConfig = serde_json::from_str(&strbuf).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result.username);

    // Note that `result` is only valid as long as `strbuf` exists.
    // i.e if `strbuf` goes out of scope or is moved to another function, we get an error. For example, the following would cause an error:
    // std::mem::drop(strbuf); // Function which moves strbuf, not a referernce
    // println!("{:?}", result.username); // Error
}
```

Depending on exactly what your concerns are, this might be less efficient than storing a String in your struct (e.g if the `example.json` is 1MB large, and you only extract a single field - the above code will store the entire 1MB string in memory only to have a few bytes worth of text accessible).