# How to pass data from request to response without copying in actix_web

Tags: rust, actix-web, zero-copy

I have a User structure that is deserialized from the request body. I want to fill the data of the User structure (field name) according to the data received from the database and return the response.

1. Without copying, borrow the username from the database data, which is stored in the global structure
2. Return a response of the same User structure with a filled-in name

I use tokio::task::spawn_blocking because there are blocking operations in the real project

```rust
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref USER_DATA: Mutex<Arc<HashMap<String, String>>> = Mutex::new(Arc::new(Default::default()));
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Default)]
struct User<'a> {
    id: &'a str,

    #[serde(skip_deserializing)]
    name: &'a str
}

struct Response<'a> {
    user: web::Json<User<'a>>,
    common_data: Arc<HashMap<String, String>>
}

impl Response<'_> {
    pub fn fill_user(mut self) -> Self {
        self.user.name = self.common_data.get(self.user.id).unwrap();
        self
    }
}

impl Responder for Response<'_> {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::OK).body(serde_json::to_string(&self.user).unwrap())
    }
}

async fn calculate(req: HttpRequest, user: web::Json<User<'static>>) -> impl Responder {

    let mut resp = Response {
        user,
        common_data: USER_DATA.lock().await.clone()
    };

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        resp.fill_user()
    }).await.unwrap()

}
```

Now I am getting this error

```
error: implementation of `_::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
  --> src\main.rs:62:46
   |
62 |             .route("/calculate", web::post().to(calculate))
   |                                              ^^ implementation of `_::_serde::Deserialize` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `User<'static>` must implement `_::_serde::Deserialize<'0>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `User<'_>` actually implements `_::_serde::Deserialize<'1>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve "implementation of serde::Deserialize is not general enough" with actix-web's Json type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976096/how-do-i-resolve-implementation-of-serdedeserialize-is-not-general-enough-wi)

Comment: You cannot use a `&str` to deserialize into, it must be a `String`.